# Is it possible to contain different classes in one type of variable in Java?

Tags: java

I have two classes, class A and class B, which each have a method with the same name. Is it possible to have one variable, maybe of type `Object`, that could be able to contain both types of classes and perform their methods?

As an example of what I mean:

```
class A {
    public void doSomething() {
        ...
    }
}

class B {
    public void doSomething() {
        ...
    }
}

class Test {
    Object obj;

    if (isTrue) 
        obj = new A();
    else
        obj = new B();

    obj.doSomething();
}
```

I looked into Reflection, but I am not sure if it can be used to do what I want or not.

Any help is cool, thanks.

Comment: If `A` and `B` were to both extend a superclass/implement an interface `C` that contains the `doSomething` method, then you can use `C c = new A()` or `C c = new B()`, and call `c.doSomething()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing you can do is create an interface and have both classes implement it. This way, you can have a single common type which you can assign these objects to and not have to do instance checks or casting.

```
public interface C {
    void doSomething();
}

public class A implements C {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
    }
}

public class B implements C {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
    }
}

public class Test {
    public C obj;

    obj = new A(); // or new B()

    obj.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe this is the solution. I will try it out and see if it is what I am looking for.

Comment: Just a note about the @Override annotation. It's not strictly required, but it does help to ensure your code isn't broken. If you accidentally spell the method wrong or put it on a method not defined in the interface (or any super type), the compiler will catch it and error.

Answer (score 1):

[Java Polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) is the key. Make your classes implement an interface defining your method:

```
interface DoSomethingable {
  void doSomething();
} 
class A implements DoSomethingable {
public void doSomething() {
    ...
  }
}
class B implements DoSomethingable {
public void doSomething() {
    ...
  }
}
class Test {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    DoSomethingable obj;

    if (isTrue) {
      obj = new A();
    } else {
      obj = new B();
    }

    obj.doSomething();
  } 
}
```